# Prevent the popup window from opening if the check failed

Tags: java, wicket

I would like to prevent the popup window from opening if the check failed? Is it possible with the following setup? Currently, it opens the popup window with the current page (with error msg) if the check failed.

```
Link myLink = new Link( "confirm-new-stuff" )
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick()
        {
            if ( Boolean.valueOf( confirmReadDocCheckbox.getValue() ) )
            {
                confirmationCheckboxFeedback.setVisible( false );
                setResponsePage( SuccessPage.class, getPageParameters() );
            }
            else
            {
                confirmationCheckboxFeedback.setVisible( true );
            }
        }
    };
    myLink.setPopupSettings( popupSettings );
    add( myLink );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write some custom JavaScript. Override `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.PopupSettings#getPopupJavaScript()` and wrap the original JavaScript produced by Wicket with your checks.